# In what currency does Emirates charge additional fees?

Tags: money, uae

Going over my receipts from UAE, the currency is almost always AED (Emirati Dirham) as expected. However I noticed that the receipts when I purchased additional baggage allowance is DHS which [XE](http://www.xe.com/) does not know and does not correspond to a currency symbol.

This DHS currency appears on two receipts from Emirates and one more from a restaurant in Dubai. What is the relation between AED and DHS? Is this is a multi-exchange rate system like in China or Cuba?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [coinmill.com](https://coinmill.com/AED_calculator.html), it's just another symbol for United Arab Emirates Dirham:

> The United Arab Emirates Dirham is the currency in United Arab Emirates (AE, ARE, UAE). The symbol for AED can be written Dh, and **Dhs**. The United Arab Emirates Dirham is divided into 100 fils. The exchange rate for the United Arab Emirates Dirham was last updated on March 2, 2018 from The International Monetary Fund. The AED conversion factor has 6 significant digits.

Seems it's a similar case as with PLN, which in Poland are commonly referred to as zł.

Comment: Or, CNY (ChiNese Yuan) is often referred to (even in English) as RMB (RenMinBi).

Comment: Or anything from this list, really https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol#List_of_presently-circulating_currency_symbols

Comment: @MichałPolitowski Which is basically everything. The ISO codes came along after most currencies had already decided on their weird signs like $ and £.

Comment: @David yeah, basically

Answer (score 14):

Dhs is just a common domestic abbreviation for dirhams. AED is the international ISO currency code.